# iBATIS Error in configuration xml

Tags: xml, ibatis, dtd, ibatis.net

i'm using iBATIS in my project. and my SqlMapConfig.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig
    PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN"
    "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">
<sqlMapConfig>
    <transactionManger type="JDBC">
        <dataSource type="SIMPLE">
            <property name="JDBC.Driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL"
                value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@apludc01dat01-oravip.com:61961:irawbp" />
            <property name="JDBC.Username" value="xxxxxx" />
            <property name="JDBC.Password" value="xxxxxx" />
        </dataSource>
    </transactionManger>
</sqlMapConfig>
```

and i'm getting following error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibatis.common.exception.NestedRuntimeException: Error occurred.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "sqlMapConfig" is incomplete, it must match "(properties?,settings?,typeAlias*,typeHandler*,transactionManager?,sqlMap+)+".
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "sqlMapConfig" is incomplete, it must match "(properties?,settings?,typeAlias*,typeHandler*,transactionManager?,sqlMap+)+".
Caused by: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "sqlMapConfig" is incomplete, it must match "(properties?,settings?,typeAlias*,typeHandler*,transactionManager?,sqlMap+)+".
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "sqlMapConfig" is incomplete, it must match "(properties?,settings?,typeAlias*,typeHandler*,transactionManager?,sqlMap+)+".
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(SqlMapConfigParser.java:81)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientBuilder.java:62)
    at com.test.DemoDB.main(DemoDB.java:16)
Caused by: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "sqlMapConfig" is incomplete, it must match "(properties?,settings?,typeAlias*,typeHandler*,transactionManager?,sqlMap+)+".
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "sqlMapConfig" is incomplete, it must match "(properties?,settings?,typeAlias*,typeHandler*,transactionManager?,sqlMap+)+".
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:53)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(SqlMapConfigParser.java:78)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "sqlMapConfig" is incomplete, it must match "(properties?,settings?,typeAlias*,typeHandler*,transactionManager?,sqlMap+)+".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.createDocument(NodeletParser.java:150)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:50)
    ... 3 more

Caused by: 
com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "sqlMapConfig" is incomplete, it must match "(properties?,settings?,typeAlias*,typeHandler*,transactionManager?,sqlMap+)+".
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "sqlMapConfig" is incomplete, it must match "(properties?,settings?,typeAlias*,typeHandler*,transactionManager?,sqlMap+)+".
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:53)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(SqlMapConfigParser.java:78)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientBuilder.java:62)
    at com.test.DemoDB.main(DemoDB.java:16)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "sqlMapConfig" is incomplete, it must match "(properties?,settings?,typeAlias*,typeHandler*,transactionManager?,sqlMap+)+".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.createDocument(NodeletParser.java:150)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:50)
    ... 3 more

Caused by: 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "sqlMapConfig" is incomplete, it must match "(properties?,settings?,typeAlias*,typeHandler*,transactionManager?,sqlMap+)+".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.createDocument(NodeletParser.java:150)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:50)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(SqlMapConfigParser.java:78)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientBuilder.java:62)
    at com.test.DemoDB.main(DemoDB.java:16)
```

What causes to this error.i know something related to DTD. But please can anybody give clear help? and please suggest a good tutorial for ibatis.

Comment: Which version of iBatis are you using?

Comment: iBATIS 1.3.1. Also i can't upgrade new version because i'm doing maintenance of existing project.

Comment: Really? com.ibatis.common.logging.LogFactory doesn't seem to exist in iBatis 1.3.1

Comment: still the problem is there.now i'm changed to all ibatis-xxx2.jar.i'm getting a new error updated above.